# Possible to have different array names when write-output PSCustomObject]@{ in my function?

Tags: arrays, powershell

Is there any way to name the variable for an array something in my  `Catch {` and then have another array name for the array inside Try/script part of my function?

Cause when i try doing like this `$computerObject = [PSCustomObject]@{`
and then doing Write-Output $computerArray i can only get either my variables inside Try/script array being displayed inside Powershell window. Or only get the `$error` message from my `Catch`.. Is there any way to name each array something so i can do like below.

`write-host "Results"`
`Write-Output $computerArray` - display my first array here

`write-host "Failed: computerlist" -foregroundcolor red`
`Write-Output $computerArray2` - display `$error` computers here. `$error` should just include computers who did not answer to ping and other stuff from my `invoke-command` computerlist.txt

The only true answer to why i need this separately is that sometimes i want my array in a CSV file. And sometimes i just want to copy info directly from Powershell window. And then its more practical to have failed computers separated and not in the same array output.

Comment: I don't see a problem with having all computers in the same output with a "Status" column, would be pretty easy to filter in excel where `Status` = `TRUE` / `FALSE`

Comment: The first array contains like 15 variables/fields of information. And i only want failed computers to exclude those and make extra "maintence work" on those clients to see why they are failing winRM connection. I tried doing `$errorArray = New-Object PSObject -Property @{` inside my `Catch {`  and then after } i tested `Write-output $errorArray` but comes up with zero results. Ive read about this on another forum post from a post with the title **"Two Single-Dimension Arrays, but Only One Shows in Output"** but never figured out a solution. Or did they?

Comment: Yeah this is doable but can you add the code you currently have?

Comment: Yes its alot to post. But its based and taken directly from this post [link](https://www.gngrninja.com/script-ninja/2016/6/18/powershell-getting-started-part-12-creating-custom-objects) right below where its written "Let's look at the code:" CTRL+F and you see that there is one array for the information, and one array itself for the `catch {` but how can i output each array on their own when they are called the same. Like above where i declare one array $errorArray. But its not working at all when i do it inside his function. And as said i use the exact same script.

Comment: You should really post the code as it's hard to guess what you're trying to accomplish by just reading about it. Based on that link you've provided, it depends on how you're passing the computer names. Are you using a `foreach` loop? Would be helpful to see what you're working with. If you are and if I understand you correctly, you just want the computers that did connect inside `$computerArray` and the computers that didn't inside another variable? Given the loop and code in the article, you can remove the content inside the `catch {` and have your own in the loop outside of how its called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This function](https://www.gngrninja.com/script-ninja/2016/6/18/powershell-getting-started-part-12-creating-custom-objects) (as mentioned in comments) doesn't leverage the [CIM cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/?view=powershell-7.2) parallel capabilities, would recommend some tweaks to it but to answer the actual question, how can you *"split"* the output between success and fail:

The function as-is, doesn't require any modification to achieve this, it's `try` and `catch` blocks are outputting objects with the same properties and luckily one of those properties is `Error` and it's value is a boolean so you can simply first query all the computers and then split the result using [`.Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.2#where) with [`Split` mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.2#split).

The code would be like this:

```
$computers = 'computer1', 'computer2', ....

$computerArray = foreach($computer in $computers) {
    Get-ComputerInformation -ComputerName $computer
}

# now we can split between FAIL and SUCCESS
$fail, $success = $computerArray.Where({ $_.Error }, 'Split')
$success | Export-Csv path\to\success.csv -NoTypeInformation
$fail | Export-Csv path\to\fail.csv -NoTypeInformation
```